# output of a program running 3 threads created by extending Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am new to Java Multi-threading and trying to figure out the output of below code that creates 3 threads a, b and c.

```java
class A extends Thread {
    int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread A started");
        while (i < 4) {
            System.out.println("\t value of i in Thread A:" + i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("ThreadA finished");
    }
}

class B extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("ThreadB started");
        while (i < 4) {
            System.out.println("\t value of i in Thread B:" + i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("ThreadB finished");
    }
}

class C extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("ThreadC started");
        while (i < 4) {
            System.out.println("\t value of i in Thread C" + i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("ThreadC finished");
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // System.out.println("Hello, World!");

        System.out.println("Main Thread started");
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(th.getName());
        System.out.println(th.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Priority of A thread " + a.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Priority of B thread " + b.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Priority of C thread " + c.getPriority());
        System.out.println();
        th.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        b.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        c.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println("Showing new Priorites \n");
        System.out.println("Priority of TH thread " + th.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Priority of A thread " + a.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Priority of B thread " + b.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Priority of C thread " + c.getPriority());
        System.out.println();
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
    }
}
```

output of above code is

```java
Main Thread started
main
5
Priority of A thread 5
Priority of B thread 5
Priority of C thread 5

Showing new Priorites

Priority of TH thread 10
Priority of A thread 5
Priority of B thread 1
Priority of C thread 5

ThreadC started
         value of i in Thread C0
Thread A started
         value of i in Thread A:0
         value of i in Thread A:1
         value of i in Thread C1
         value of i in Thread C2
         value of i in Thread C3
ThreadC finished
ThreadB started
         value of i in Thread A:2
         value of i in Thread A:3
ThreadA finished
         value of i in Thread B:0
         value of i in Thread B:1
         value of i in Thread B:2
         value of i in Thread B:3
ThreadB finished
```

I know that after calling start() method, threads become runnable and ready to be picked by thread scheduler.

From output we can see thread C started running its run() method first, then it should have completed its run() method. But how does run() method of thread a is executing before completion of run() method of thread C?
Somebody please help here.

Comment: Preemptive multitasking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#PREEMPTIVE

Comment: On some systems, it's possible `A`, `B` and `C` are all running at the same time. This is usually the **point** of multi-threading. Why would you need multiple threads of execution if everything executed serially anyway?

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, for your response. That's why I am getting different output on different machines.

Comment: By the way, in modern Java we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. We use the Executors framework to abstract away the threads and thread pools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on thread priorities.  This is what the [Oracle JRockit documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs142/devapp/codeprac.html#998533) says:

> ### Don't Depend on Thread Priorities
>
> Be careful when using `java.lang.Thread.setPriority`. Depending on
> thread priorities might lead on unwanted or unexpected results since
> the scheduling algorithm might choose to starve lower priority threads
> of CPU time and never execute them. Furthermore the result might
> differ between operating systems and JVMs.
>
> The Java API specification states that "Every thread has a priority.
> Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads
> with lower priority."
>
> The priority set by the `setPriority()` method is a parameter that
> might be used in the thread-scheduling algorithm, which shares CPU
> execution time between executing threads. This algorithm might be
> controlled either by the JVM or by the operating system. It is
> important to be aware of the fact that this algorithm normally differs
> between operating systems and that the algorithm might change between
> releases of both the operating system and the JVM. For BEA JRockit JVM
> native threads, the algorithm is implemented by the operating system.

What you have observed is the *effects* of the system specific behavior of thread scheduling ... as described by the above documentation (for example).

Comment: "For BEA JRockit JVM" -- I worked for BEA (That's a blast from the past).